# POSTing `JSON` to an `ArrayList` results in an empty List

Tags: json, arraylist, resteasy

I have a problem POSTing `JSON` to an `ArrayList`

I have a class Plan

```
 public class Plan {
    private String planId;
    private String planName;
        :
        :
}
```

and an `ArrayList` of Plan - PlanList

```
public class PlanList {
    private List<Plan> plans = new ArrayList<Plan>();
        :
        :
}
```

I have the following POST and GET REST APIs

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public PlanList createPlans(@CookieParam(SmsHttpHeaders.X_SMS_AUTH_TOKEN) String token, PlanList plans, @HeaderParam("Organization-Id") String organizationIdByService);

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public PlanList retrieveAllPlans(@CookieParam(SmsHttpHeaders.X_SMS_AUTH_TOKEN) String token, @HeaderParam("Organization-Id") String organizationIdByService);
```

I POST the following JSON using Postman, following the same format that is returned by the GET.

```
{
  "plans": [
    {
      "planId":"1",
      "planName":"Plan 1"
    },
    {
      "planId":"2",
      "planName":"Plan 2"
    },
    {
      "planId":"3",
      "planName":"Plan 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I hit the breakpoint at the start of createPlans(), the argument *plans* is an empty `List`.
Is the JSON incorrectly formatted? Is my REST definition wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` from [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/) library :

```
//instantiate plan1 
JSONObject plan1 = new JSONObject();
plan1.put("planId", 1);
plan1.put("planName", "Plan 1");

//or by passing a String if you want:
JSONObject plan2 = new JSONObject("{\"planId\":2, \"planName\":\"Plan 2\"}");

//put plan1 and plan2 in your Json array
JSONArray plans = new JSONArray();
plans.put(plan1);
plans.put(plan2);

System.out.println(plan1);
//returns: {"planName":"Plan 1","planId":1}

System.out.println(plans);
//returns: [{"planName":"Plan 1","planId":1},{"planName":"Plan 2","planId":1}]
```

Comment: I am  not clear how this solves my problem, since I am POSTing the JSON as a string to my List. I am not trying to build a JSON object.

Comment: Instead of building Plan and PlanList classes, you can just use the already-built JSONObject and JSONArray.
You can create them passing the POSTed string as I did for plan2.